# Lense-Thirring effect around rotating black holes

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, rotational-dynamics

The Lense-Thirring angular velocity of a particle around a rotating black hole in the weak-field limit is given by the formula
$$\omega=\frac{2J}{r^3}$$
where J is the angular momentum of the black hole. The above equation is written in spherical polar coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$. Since weak-field limit is considered the $\theta-$ dependence is not useful in the above equation. However, very close to the black hole, I think the dependence on $\theta$ may be important.

Can someone suggest me how to obtain the $\theta-$ dependence of the above equation. I couldn't find any reference where this is calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for the frame-dragging frequency for the co-rotating reference frame around a Kerr black hole is given by
$$
\omega=\frac{2 J r}{\left(\frac{J^2}{M^2}+r^2\right) \left(\frac{J^2 \cos ^2(\theta )}{M^2}+r^2\right)+\frac{2 J^2 r \sin ^2(\theta )}{M}}.
$$
This result is well known in literature here expressed in natural units $G=c=1$ and in terms of $J$ and $M$. I do not know what exactly you mean with *"Since weak-field limit is considered the $\theta$− dependence is not useful in the above equation."* but if one expands the exact expression for $\omega$ for large radii we get
$$
\omega = \frac{2 J}{r^3}-\frac{2 J^3 \left(\cos ^2\theta+1\right)}{M^2 r^5}+O\left(\left(\frac{r}{M}\right)^{-6}\right).
$$
The first $\theta$-independent term is the one quoted in the question and the next-to-leading order (NLO) term $J^3$ carries a $\theta$-dependence. The NLO term decays rapidly with $r^{-5}$ and thus as already hinted in the question the $\theta$-dependence in this expansion becomes relevant only for small radii $r$. Wether or rather to what extend this expansion is justified close to the black hole (for small $r/M$ needs to be evaluated for a given explicit scenario. The weak-field limit (in the sense of large $r$) is probably not very well suited for the study of motion close to the black hole.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I was looking for the same answer. By "since weak-field limit is considered the $\theta-$ dependence is not useful in the above equation", I meant that the $\theta-$ dependence is not important at large distances, the relevant details that you explained in the last paragraph.

Comment: One more question I would like to ask: Is this frame dragging angular velocity same as the Lense-Thirring precession rate (in the weak field limit) as the expressions for both of them are the same, i.e., $2J/r^3$?

Comment: @Richard It seems that there are different frequencies depending on what observer one considers. $\omega$ in this answer is the angular velocity of a 'locally nonrotating observer'. The 'Lense-Thirring recession rate' (of a spinning test gyroscop) (see e.g. 'Lense-Thirring precession in strong gravitational fields' by C. Chakraborty) is something else. See Eqs. (1), (3) and (7) of the aforementioned paper.

Comment: In the paper you cited, the author writes in the first sentence, "Stationary spacetimes with angular momentum (rotation) are known to exhibit an effect called Lense-Thirring (LT) precession whereby locally inertial frames are dragged along the rotating spacetime ..." Since the LT precession is also due to the dragging of inertial frames, I couldn't understand the difference between LT and frame dragging effects.